# Updated Python is not working with other packages - how do I fix this?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, install.packages, downgrade

My computer is in chaos right now because I tried to update Python. I updated to 3.11.4 and all of a sudden a bunch of packages are having issues. Specifically, gala is unable to be installed entirely.

I've tried completely uninstalling Anaconda Navigator and completely re-installing it. Then when I run "pip install gala" it like runs for a really long time in CMD and prints a bunch of "DEBUG" info then says "Solving Environment:" and has the waiting symbol for literally ever. Like last time it was 3 hours that I finally gave up and shut it off. It never ends. When I try to downgrade Python to what I used to use with Gala (3.8.8) it does the same thing and refuses to downgrade Python (using conda install python=3.8.8). What on Earth do I do? I literally started from scratch even and this is bad because all my work is dependent on this package :(

Everything was working fine before I tried updating packages.

Tried uninstalling Anaconda Navigator entirely and re-installing. Packages aren't working. Python refuses to downgrade. I don't know if there is some issue in my computer or what.

Here's the end of the error message (the actual error is pages long):

```
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\potential\src
      copying gala\potential\src\funcdefs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\potential\src
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      copying gala\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      copying gala\tests\optional_deps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      copying gala\tests\setup_package.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      copying gala\tests\test_units.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      copying gala\tests\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\gala\tests
      running build_ext
      Compiling gala/cconfig.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing gala/cconfig.pyx
      building 'gala._cconfig' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gala
Failed to build gala
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gala, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

And here is a message that comes a bunch of times for various packages within gala:

---

```
          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'gala.tests' as an importable package[^1],
          but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

          This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
          package, please make sure that 'gala.tests' is explicitly added
          to the `packages` configuration field.

          Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

          You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

          If you don't want 'gala.tests' to be distributed and are
          already explicitly excluding 'gala.tests' via
          `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
          you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
          combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

          You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


          [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                directory, all directories are treated like packages.
          ********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Please post the complete output of the `pip install gala` and `conda install python==3.8.8` commands.

Comment: Okay, I updated the post with the error message. It's many pages long but the **** <insert message> **** happens a bunch of times in a row just replacing a different gala.<insert name> into it. I tried downloading the Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 as it said but not sure what it does in this case since I'm working in Python.

Comment: The first error indicates that the script needs to compile something and your system doesn't have a suitable compiler. The immediate solution is to install the recommended compiler. There's probably additional useful information in the redacted portion.

Comment: AFAIK you should never mess with the system python; too many installed packages depend on it. Instead, use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for each of your projects or any python code that needs a different version. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelRuth Yeah!! So I tried to do that and downloaded it and everything but it is still giving me that error which is unfortunate :/

Comment: @Robert Thanks!! I haven't used virtual environments in the past which I'm realizing now likely created problems but may also try to do this now